# Switch monitor position in Weston

Tags: wayland

Is it possible to indicate monitor position in Weston/Wayland?

I have two monitors and been testing the Weston compositor, but I have been unable to indicate which monitor should be the main one (or which one should show the "left part" of the screen).

Checking the weston.ini docs (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/weston.ini.5.html) I found info about setting resolution, scaling and transform/rotation, but nothing about the position of the monitors.

Comment: Did you find a way to achieve what you were looking for here?

Answer (score 3):

I have been interested into the same some weeks ago. I send the question to the wayland IRC channel.

You can have a look at:

- <s>https://people.freedesktop.org/~cbrill/dri-log/index.php?channel=wayland&highlight_names=&date=2017-12-19</s>
- <s>https://people.freedesktop.org/~cbrill/dri-log/index.php?channel=wayland&highlight_names=&date=2017-12-20</s>

Here is the relevant part:

> 22:31 maggu2810: Is there any change to change the display / output position in weston? I am using three outputs but don't know how to configure which one if left / right of the other one.
>
> 22:33 maggu2810: ... chance to change ...
>
> 22:35 maggu2810: the output sections in weston.ini currently contains the name, the mode and the scale. I didn't find any "position" option or anything that looks like an option to modify the "order" of the displays.
>
> 07:07 pq: maggu2810, yes, not implemented yet, there were indeed some WIP patches in 2016

Perhaps you will be able to post a feature request in their mailing list. I don't think they will look for feature requests on SO ;)

Comment: You're right the developers are not likely to check SO :P. It's that I tried to find a support channel listed on the Wayland docs and didn't find any. Tried to log into their IRC channel but seems restricted. Si I thought let's try SO ;). I've tried sway and found it already includes the option I'm looking for: the ability to "swap" the monitors, so I think most other Wayland compositors should support it and it'd be a matter of time it gets added to Weston.